# Find all values that $f(0),g(0)$ can take

Tags: functions

If $f,g$ are functions from reals to reals that satisfy:

$$f(x+y)=f(x)g(y)+g(x)f(y)\quad   \&\quad  g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)+f(x)f(y)$$

Then find all values that $f(0),g(0)$ can take.

It is easy to see if such functions exists then $f(0)=0,g(0)=1$ But we should find functions that satisfy the condition to complete the proof.Please write the idea that you use for finding the function.

Comment: Well, if $f,g$ are both identically $0$ then your relations hold but $g(0)\neq 1$.

Comment: As to a more interesting example, Hint:  these look a lot like the addition formulas for the trig functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the equations, with $h(x)=g(x)^2-f(x)^2$, we immediately obtain $$h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)\tag1.$$ So $h(0)^2=h(0)$, i.e. $h(0)=0$ or $h(0)=1$. Since $h(x)=h(x)h(0)$, we have $h$ identical $0$ in the former case, and $g(0)=h(0)=1$ in the latter case.
However, (1) may have very irregular solutions besides $h(x)=e^{cx}$. Under suitable regularity conditions, the non-trivial solutions are $f(x)=e^{ax}\sinh bx$ and $g(x)=e^{ax}\cosh bx$.
If you want to know how: $g(x)+f(x)$ and $g(x)-f(x)$ satisfy (1), too, so they are exponentials as well, if sufficiently regular. We don't have to assume differentiability, the assumption of continuity at $0$ is sufficient.